# javascript bug in firefox with string manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function in javascript. It works in every browser except firefox. There seems to be some problems with the substring keyword in this browser.

```
function EvalMonthYear() {

    var RawMonth = $.trim( $('#MonthList').val() );
    var SpacePosition = RawMonth.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;

    var TheYear = $.trim(RawMonth.substring(SpacePosition, RawMonth.lenght));
    var TheMonth = IndexOfMonth($.trim(RawMonth.substring(0, SpacePosition)));
};
```

MonthList contains a month/year string such as January 2011 or May 2009. The goal is to fill the variables TheYear and TheMonth so that it works in every browser.

If you've run into this problem and can think of a good solution this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function EvalMonthYear() {
    var RawMonth = $.trim( $('#MonthList').val() );
    var MonthYear = RawMonth.split(" ");

    var TheYear = MonthYear[1];
    var TheMonth = MonthYear[0];
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to rewrite

```
RawMonth.lenght
```

as

```
RawMonth.length
```

Your original code works in Firefox 4b11 for me, so it might be an issue with 3.6. I'm guessing that your typo works in most browsers because `RawMonth.lenght` is `undefined`, which is similar to not passing in the argument. (It's a little different, if you inspect the `arguments` array.)